# Colour nodes in tikz independently

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

Good afternoon,

I would like to know how to colour the nodes A and Y in another colour (grey for example) without changing the colour of the other two nodes.

Best regards.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=1cm and 1cm,
  mynode/.style={draw,circle,text width=0.5cm,align=center}
]

\node[mynode] (z) {A};
\node[mynode,right=of z] (x) {Y};
\node[mynode,left=of z] (y) {$U_A$};
\node[mynode,right=of x] (w) {$U_Y$};

\path (x) edge[latex-] (z);
\path (y) edge[latex-] (z);
\path (x) edge[latex-] (w);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Graph.}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Then you can just add the color information to the options of the respective `node`s. You can choose to change the color of the frame using `draw=red`, the background using `fill=red` or the font using `text=red`. It affects only the one node, not the others. So it will look something like `\node[mynode,draw=red] (z) {A};`. This will also overwrite the general `draw` command from the style.

Comment: Another option is to create a second node style, like `mynode2/.style={mynode,draw=red}` that inherit every argument from `mynode` and gets the different colour, and then call this `mynode2` style when needed.

Comment: Any news, @PacoteMicasa?

Answer (score 2):

When you write `draw` it means a black outline for the node, and no `fill` has been mentioned

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=1cm and 1cm,
  mynode/.style={draw,circle,text width=0.5cm,align=center}
]

\node[mynode, draw=red,fill=gray] (z) {A};
\node[mynode,right=of z,draw=green, fill=black!20] (x) {Y};
\node[mynode,left=of z] (y) {$U_A$};
\node[mynode,right=of x] (w) {$U_Y$};

\path (x) edge[latex-] (z);
\path (y) edge[latex-] (z);
\path (x) edge[latex-] (w);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Graph.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define `my node` with two arguments: first for color of edge and the second for fill color. For example. Let me rename it to `V`:

```
V/.style args = {#1/#2}{circle, draw=#1, semithick, fill=#2,
                        text width=2.1em, inner sep=0pt, align=center,
                        on chain},
```

Using `chains` for positioning of nodes (together with `positioning` library), and `arrows.meta` for defining arrows heads, complete MWE (focused only on images) can be:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}


\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1cm and 1cm,
  start chain = V going right, % nodes are in chain with name V
V/.style args = {#1/#2}{circle, draw=#1, semithick, fill=#2, % <--- arguments for colors
                        text width=2.1em, inner sep=0pt, align=center,
                        on chain}, % nodes are in chain
   V/.default = black/white,       % default nodes colors
every edge/.style = {draw,-{Triangle[angle=45:2pt 4]}}
                        ] 
\node[V]                {$U_A$};    % node name is V-1, node has default colors
\node[V=red/gray]       {$A$};
\node[V=teal/gray!30]   {$Y$};
\node[V]                {$U_Y$};    % node name is V-4
%
\path   (V-2) edge  (V-1)
        (V-2) edge  (V-3)
        (V-3) edge  (V-4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]